# Taking the limit of a Beta Distribution to yield the Gamma Distribution

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, gamma-distribution, beta-distribution

The Poisson Distribution may be obtained from the Binomial Distribution by keeping $\lambda = np$ fixed and taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Similarly, the Gamma Distribution may be obtained by starting from the Negative Binomial Distribution by again fixing $\lambda = np$, and also setting $r,$ the number of failures, to $r = xn$, then taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Well, the conjugate prior of the Poisson Distribution also happens to be the Gamma Distribution, i.e. we use it represent uncertainty in the rate parameter. Whereas the conjugate prior of the Binomial distribution is the Beta distribution, i.e. we use it to represent uncertainty in the probability of success, $p.$

**Question: Can we obtain the Gamma Distribution by taking the limit of the Beta Distribution in the same manner?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Special_and_limiting_cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $X\sim\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,n).$ Consider the limit of the distribution of $nX$ as $n\to\infty.$

\begin{align}
f_{nX}(x) = {} & \frac d{dx} \Pr(nX\le x) = \frac d{dx} \Pr\left( X\le\frac xn\right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac d{dx}\int_0^{x/n} \text{constant} \cdot u^{\alpha-1} (1-u)^{n-1} \, du \\[8pt]
= {} & \text{constant} \cdot \left( \frac xn \right)^{\alpha-1} \left( 1 - \frac xn \right)^{n-1} \cdot \frac 1n
\end{align}
Recall from calculus that the limit of $ \displaystyle \left( 1 - \frac xn\right)^{n-1}$ as $n\to\infty$ is $e^{-x}.$

Thus you have
$$
\left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \begin{array}{l} \text{an expression} \\ \text{with no $x$ in it} \end{array} \right) \right) \cdot x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}.
$$
The limit of the expression with no $x$ in it must be $1/\Gamma(\alpha)$ since the integral of this whole thing over the interval $(0,+\infty)$ must be $1.$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the integral over the Beta Distribution:

$\int^1_0Beta(x;\alpha,\beta)dx = \int^1_0\frac{(\alpha + \beta -1)!}{(\alpha -1)!(\beta-1)!}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx=1$

Transforming variables to $\lambda=nx$ and setting $\beta = nt$ yields:

$\int^n_0\frac{(\alpha + nt -1)!}{(\alpha -1)!(nt-1)!}(\frac{\lambda}{n})^{\alpha-1}(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{nt-1}\frac{d\lambda}{n}=1$

Why $\beta = nt$? Because $\beta$ represents the number of observed failures. So naturally, in a Poisson process, there are going to be many more failures than successes (kept track of by $\alpha$). The successes are still finite, but $\beta$ becomes infinite.

Taking the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ yields the continuous analog of the Beta distribution:

$\int^\infty_0\frac{t^\alpha \lambda^{\alpha -1}}{(\alpha -1)!}e^{-\lambda t}d\lambda = \int^\infty_0Gamma(\lambda;\alpha,t)d\lambda = 1$

Note that naively taking the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ of $Beta(\lambda/n;\alpha,nt)$ results in a factor of n, i.e.$n\cdot Gamma(\lambda,\alpha,t)$. Transformation of variables from $x$ to $\lambda$ introduces a factor of $n$ in the denominator which cancels it out.